# Changing package name breaks JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface, cmusphinx

I try to use the pocketsphinx package for my app and need to rename the [demo package](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/) name to something usefull (eg com.myname.foo)

I spent hours on figuring out, but I simply can't get it to work.

The problem is, that the project runs fine if I leave the package name and works without any problems (apart from random crashes), but when I rename it, i get the error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: new_Config__SWIG_0
```

I already tried modifying the Swig command, but it didn't work either.

Any ideas?

I only changed the Manifest's package name declariation and the package folder of the normal Activity.

Comment: have you tried to update Android.mk which is this folder PocketSphinxDemo/jni ???  you need update the paths within this file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as far as I am concerned, there are no paths that need to be changed, as the only path that changed is the `/PROJECT/src/...` path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sooo, I found the problem; I spend 20 ****ing hours just to find out, that I actually forgot to add

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("pocketsphinx_jni");
}
```

to the Activity class. I can't believe I didn't see that, but thanks for all the answers! +1 for everyone helping me :]

Answer (score 6):

You need to change on the c/c++ side there are two posible ways depending on how your JNI is implemented.

A. The function name contains the full classpath

    `JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_"package with underscore instead of .""class""method"(JNIEnv *env, jclass class,...`

e.g.

`JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_android_mms_transaction_NativeSms_send(JNIEnv *env, jclass class,...`

match method send in class NativeSms in package com.android.mms.transaction

B. There is a string supplied back to dalvik/javaVM with the classpath. Look for someting like this:

```
    static int registerMethods(JNIEnv* env) {
    static const char* const kClassName =
        "com/example/android/platform_library/PlatformLibrary";
    jclass clazz;

    /* look up the class */
    clazz = env->FindClass(kClassName);
    if (clazz == NULL) {
        LOGE("Can't find class %s\n", kClassName);
        return -1;
    }

    /* register all the methods */
    if (env->RegisterNatives(clazz, gMethods,
            sizeof(gMethods) / sizeof(gMethods[0])) != JNI_OK)
    {
        LOGE("Failed registering methods for %s\n", kClassName);
        return -1;
    }
    ...
```

Edit 2011-12-07 Clarified first example

Comment: I really hoped this work, but sadly there is no such classpath on the c side :(
And like I said above, the only thing that was changed was the Android's Manifest declaration and the source dir, but **not** the JNI package name...

Comment: looking at the code you linked to there is alot of functions like Java_edu_cmu_pocketsphinx_pocketsphinxJNI_Config_1exists() in the jni/pockectsphinx_wrap.c that match to functions in jni/edu/cmu/pocketspinx/pocketsphinxJNI.java like public final static native boolean Config_exists(long jarg1, Config jarg1_, String jarg2); (in class pocketsphinxJNI package edu.cmu.pocketsphinx )

Comment: That is actually generated code by Swig, that changes if I change the Swig Paramters. And still, this package name remains the same (edu.cmu.pocketsphinx) (as it is in `PROJECT/jni` folder, but I changed the package name in `PROJECT/src`

Comment: Is there some problem when you rerun Swig, if you check the files after it has been executed and check the autogenerated names above to see that package names and functions namne has changed both in Java and C (the outputed .jar/.so files maybe they need to be re-copied in you build to some other folder where the android project finds them)

Comment: I found the problem, see my answer below. But *thank you so much* for you help! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have link command issue it's most likely you forgot to change the SWIG launch properties. The file is

> .externalToolBuilders/SWIG.launch

Those properties have several places to mention edu.cmu.sphinx package.

If you changed something it's recommended to describe the changes more precisely. Most likely you just forgot some small thing. For example you can pack whole changed code into archive and upload it somewhere.

Comment: It would be easier to change the launch parameters via Project/Builders/SWIG -> edit ;-) I already tried that, but it's not the problem. Thanks though!